# Commutator of positive semidefinite Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, hamiltonian, commutator

I have the following questions about the commutator of positive semidefinite Hamiltonians.

1. Under what condition, the commutator will be positive semidefinite?
2. Under what condition, the commutator will not be positive semidefinite?

I was not able to find a related result from a Google Scholar search.

Answer (score 4):

Commutators or hermitian operators -- and thus, in particular, of positive operators -- are *never* positive semi-definite. (Unless they are zero, of course.)

There's several ways to understand this (which differ in where they apply, and what they imply about the spectrum of the commutator).

---

One way to see this is to note that  commutators of hermitian operators are *antisymmetric*, as one can easily check: If $C=AB-BA$, then
$$
C^\dagger = -A^\dagger B^\dagger + B^\dagger A^\dagger = -C\ .
$$
Anti-hermitian operators $C$, however, have purely imaginary eigenvalues (since $iC$ is hermitian and thus has real eigenvalues). Note that this holds both in finite and infinite dimensions.

---

A different way of noting this is the fact that (in finite dimensions) commutators are traceless: This means that the trace, i.e., the sum of the eigenvalues, is *zero*. Thus, there cannot only be non-negative eigenvalues, unless all are zero. Note that this argument does not require hermitian matrices.

Note that in *infinite* dimensions, the commutator of non-hermitian operators can indeed be positive: For instance, $[x,ip]=\mathrm{Id}\ge 0$.